# Two row layout - Second row content vertical aligned

Tags: html, css, web, vertical-alignment

Have a eye on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTMYm/)

I want to reach a 2 row layout. With a header and the content. The header has a fixed height. The content should be in the center of the second row. But I don't know how to center the content vertical.

I tried to assign the content with `position: absolute` and `margin: auto`. Worked, but the text slid behind the header when you resize the browser small enough.

Maybe a `div` who covers the full second row containing the content would do the trick, but I can't manage this. I want to avoid `table` tags.

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Comment: @OriShuss Edited: "But I don't know how to center the content vertical."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pure CSS solution. using `calc` (CSS3)

see that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/bTMYm/5/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Site">
    <header class="Header">
        <!-- content -->
    </header>
    <div class="ContentContainer">
        <span class="Centerer"></span>
        <div class="Content">
            <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0">
                <li>
                    Text
                </li>
                <li>
                    Text
                </li>
                <li>
                    Text
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
.Site
{
    height: 100%;
}
.Header
{
    height: 120px;
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.ContentContainer
{
    background-color: azure;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
}
 .Centerer
{
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 .Content
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### OR: *Cleaner Version* (using `calc` + pseudo elements) [*Working Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/bTMYm/4/)

```
<div class="Site">
    <header class="Header">
        <!-- content -->
    </header>
    <div class="ContentContainer">
        <div class="Content">
            <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0">
                <li>
                    Text
                </li>
                <li>
                    Text
                </li>
                <li>
                    Text
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
.Site
{
    height: 100%;
}
.Header
{
    height: 120px;
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.ContentContainer
{
    background-color: azure;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
}
.ContentContainer:after
{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 .Content
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can you add `text-align: center;` to **.ContentContainer** for horizontal center alignment?

Comment: Updated my answer + add the horizontal alignment.

Comment: Works perfect! Appreciate your help. Thanks!